# images doesn't load in jsf when i use authentication filter

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, uri, servlet-filters

i use Authentication filter . this is a part of the filter :

```
if (reqURI.indexOf("/index.xhtml") >= 0)
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
else
    resp.sendRedirect(reqt.getContextPath() + "/JSFViews/Login.xhtml");
```

and in jsf pages i have images for example

```
<h:graphicImage library="image" name="logo.png" />
```

but the images doesn't load because of filter . i also change my code

```
if (reqURI.indexOf("/index.xhtml") >= 0 || reqURI.indexOf("/image") >= 0)
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
else
    resp.sendRedirect(reqt.getContextPath() + "/JSFViews/Login.xhtml");
```

but it doesn't work. what should i do?

Comment: Can you access them if you remove a filter at all?

Comment: @RomanC yes. it is completely correct

Comment: I believe the graphicImage will render to something like <img src="/JSFViews/faces/javax.faces.resource/logo.png?ln=image" alt="" /> (check the html). So your check won't work. You could test for for example "javax.faces.resource", but I think it would be better to check if the user is logged in by looking in the session (or a SessionScoped bean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String servletPath = request.getServletPath();

if (servletPath.equals("/JSFViews/index.xhtml") || servletPath.startsWith(ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER))
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
else
    resp.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/JSFViews/Login.xhtml");
```

Comment: thanks a lot. you help me a lot. my problem has been solves. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the condition to filter resources based on file extension.

```
if (reqURI.indexOf("/index.xhtml") >= 0 || new URI(reqURI).getPath().endsWith(".png"))
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
```